# Why won't header redirect work after login?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a login page with login form , it should redirect to admin page when admin loggs in. This all worked, but four days ago it redirects again to login page. When I manualy type admin after login in url, admin page can be accessed.

My login page:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
        <?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimumscale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Login - Admin</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' />
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="container_vanjski">
        <div id="container">
       
            <form method="post">
                <br/>
                <?php
                
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
                    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']));
                    if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
                        echo '&nbsp<p>Polja su prazna !</p>';
                    }
                    else {
                        $check_login = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, user_level FROM korisnici WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
                        
                                                             
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($check_login) == 1){
                            $run = mysqli_fetch_array($check_login);
                            $user_id = $run['id'];
                            $user_level = $run['user_level'];
               
                            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                                header("Location: admin");                     
                        }else{
                            echo '&nbsp<p>Pogrešno Korisničko ime ili Lozinka!</p>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
                <br/>
                <div id="log"> 
            
            <label for="username">Korisničko ime:</label><input type="text" name="username" /><br />
            <label for="password">Lozinka:</label><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Prijava" id="button" />
            
                </div>
        </form>
 
        </div>
        
        <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On my localhost server this is working, but on web server(BLUEHOST) this stopped working four days ago.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use header after html.

Two solutions :

**Header before any html code** (my favorite)

**buffering**

```
 <?php
    ob_start( );
?>
<html>
    <body>
        some output
        <?php
            ob_end_clean( );
            header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' );
            exit;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
      ob_end_flush( );
?>
```

Full code :

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
        $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']));
        if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
            $message = '&nbsp<p>Polja su prazna !</p>';
        }
        else {
            $check_login = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, user_level FROM korisnici WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");


            if(mysqli_num_rows($check_login) == 1){
                $run = mysqli_fetch_array($check_login);
                $user_id = $run['id'];
                $user_level = $run['user_level'];

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    header("Location: admin");                     
            }else{
                $message = '&nbsp<p>Pogrešno Korisničko ime ili Lozinka!</p>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimumscale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Login - Admin</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' />
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="container_vanjski">
        <div id="container">

            <form method="post">
                <br/>
                <?php echo (isset($message) ? $message : ''); ?>
                <br/>
                <div id="log"> 

            <label for="username">Korisničko ime:</label><input type="text" name="username" /><br />
            <label for="password">Lozinka:</label><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Prijava" id="button" />

                </div>
        </form>

        </div>

        <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show me how to move code before any html code? I moved it and doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't working, it doesn't get  username and password from labels on submit button?

Comment: I can't help you if you do not provide more information about the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Headers must be sent before any other content is generated on the server. Move your login handling code to the start of the file before the opening HTML tag. It may have worked on your localhost as some configurations can be a little forgiving with header's being sent mid code but it is not compliant and you will probably find that is the issue.

Comment: Move the PHP code that is in the middle of your page to the top of your page before the opening `<html>` tag and then any messages that need to be returned from it can be saved as variables and echo'ed out if they exist using `if(isset($message)){echo($message)}`. As long as nothing has been sent to the buffer or browser before the header is sent then everything is all good.

Comment: When I move entire php code from middle to top before <html> tag, it won't connect to login page because form is in <body> tag. Can you post the moved code?